# Array Iteration closure with index in swift -iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, closures, iteration

I am wondering Is there a shortcut to make the code following simple?

- Index are getting from Foreach closure instead of auto-increment set by myself (any keyword provide by library)?
- Passing "index" into my onSectionSelected as an argument?

  ```
  var index = 0
  [view_a, view_b, view_c, view_d].forEach{
      $0?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      $0?.tag = index
      index += 1
      let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSectionSelected))
      $0?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  }

  func onSectionSelected() {
      //do something for touchUpInside event
  }
  ```

Emphasise that I clearly understand how to use (index, value), array. enumerated to express this. Please answer accordingly.

Comment: Having that many `$0?.` is a pretty clear sign that you should unwrap `$0` and assign it to a local, non-optional variable

Comment: use for (index, value) in array.enumerated() { }

Comment: It definitely not duplicate cus no where i could able to find answer

Comment: @PeterGuo I suggest you read it again, more carefully, then